# Scrcpy not showing an application

Tags: screen

i have installed scrcpy recently, everything works fine except one application pydroid. when i open my applicatio in laptop using scrcpy ,  application freezes and it gets freeze .after exit the app,it shows normal and works fine. 
what would be the issue ? can anbody help? thankyou

Comment: Is this Ubuntu related?

Comment: ya , i have an ubuntu system installed. not sure if its issue with ubuntu or scrcpy

Comment: scrcpy is an application used to show android screen , like an android mirror

Comment: Install `inxi` and **[edit]** your question to provide the output of `inxi -SCGxxz`.

Comment: ok sure thankyou , i will update it

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer the myself
It's problem with the transfer type in USB
you have to select one of the option out of four options where you can find MTP transfer etc

Comment: pls enhance you answer with pictures or a more detailed description of which opion to choose - perhaps a step by step might be helpful